# Getting Instagram post caption used in an Ad in Meta Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, facebook-business-sdk

I'm retrieving data from Meta Ads using the Graph API. I need to view what is the caption of the Instagram Posts that were advertised - because in these captions there is specific words I must identify. I must be able to retrieve this post caption alongside the Ad ID that used it, otherwise it won't be useful for me.

Is there a way to do that?

I've already tried to use AdCreative endpoints, but it was no use as it didn't return me the post caption. I don't know, I might have missed some information.

Comment: `effective_instagram_story_id` is "The ID of an Instagram post to display as an Instagram ad", according to docs - I am guessing that is what you are referring to? You would need to use this ID, to go look up the details of that post then - assuming, you actually have access to the post.